# How to correctly generate an XML resource file during build?

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, build, code-generation

I need a raw XML file ("raw" as in accessible through `@raw/filename`) to be generated during the build process.

I've been trying to accomplish this using a custom Gradle task hooked on `preBuild`. This task would then gather all requirements needed and generate the file under `build/intermediates/res/main/raw`.

It's all good up to this point; I could see the file being properly generated. However, I couldn't seem to access it from any other XML resource files that I have.

I've tried changing the target directory to `build/generated/source/res/main/raw` but the problem persists.

Changing it to `src/main/res/raw` worked but then I'd have to exclude the generated file from git – I don't want that. Plus, it seems weird to have generated source files reside within the same directory as their written counterparts.

Below is a simplified snippet of my custom task:

```
task(generateChangelogXml) {
    def source = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "CHANGELOG")
    def targetDir = new File(projectDir, "/build/intermediates/res/main/raw")
    def target = new File(targetDir, "changelog_latest.xml")

    def versionName = ""
    def releaseDate = ""
    def changes = new ArrayList<String>()

    def reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(source))
    def currLine = ""
    while ((currLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        // Truncated for brevity
    }

    target.withWriter { writer ->
        writer.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n")
        writer.write("<changelog bulletedList=\"true\">\n")
        writer.write("    <changelogversion changeDate=\"\" versionName=\"$versionName\">\n")
        changes.forEach { change ->
            writer.write("        <changelogtext>$change</changelogtext>\n")
        }
        writer.write("    </changelogversion>\n")
        writer.write("</changelog>\n")
    }
}
preBuild.dependsOn(generateChangelogXml)
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, so after reading more on the matter I came to learn that we really can't rely on existing folders (be it in `generated` or `intermediates`) to put our generated files in as they might be overridden by other tasks and/or not readable at all.

The solution? Why, just create a folder of our own! As an example, this is what I'm ended up using:

```
def generatedResDir = new File("$buildDir/generated/local/main/res")
```

Then, just use it as the base directory for every generated resource files. If you're like me and are looking to generate a `raw` XML, then do this:

```
def targetDir = new File("$generatedResDir/raw")
def target = new File(targetDir, "changelog_latest.xml")
```

Last but definitely not least, add `generatedResDir` as a source directory by doing so:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        res {
            srcDirs += generatedResDir
        }
    }
}
```

You should now able to generate any files of your choosing without problems.

Comment: Hello @HadiSatrio , where i should write this code? i want to generate `.xml` file during `building_process`.

Comment: Create your custom task: `task generaetMyRes(){//place create file code here}` and then make it dependent to `preBuild` task - place this code right after task: `preBuild.dependsOn generaetMyRes`